# Why isn't the label animation working till the last value of the loop?

Tags: python, animation, tkinter

I am new to python and I have been learning tkinter recently. So I thought with myself that using the **grid_forget()** function I can remove a widget and redefine it. I thought of this animation that changes the padding of a label so it would create space (kind of like moving the label but not exactly). However, the animation does not work at all. The program freezes until the label reaches the last value of the padding. How can I fix this? Or is there a better way to animate a label moving in the screen?
Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
lbl = Label(root, text='------')
lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)


def animation():
    padding = 0
    while padding < 31:
        lbl.grid_forget()
        padding += 1
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=padding)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        # alternative: root.after(200, lambda: lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=padding))


btn = Button(root, text='Animate', command=animation)
btn.grid(row=1, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There is definitely a better way to do animation. There are lots of examples on this site. The correct way to animate is based on calling `after`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the screen for changes to be shown.

Here is a working version using the .update() method:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
lbl = Label(root, text='------')
lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)


def animation():
    padding = 0
    while padding < 31:
        lbl.grid_forget()
        padding += 1
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=padding)
        root.update()
        time.sleep(0.2)
        # alternative: root.after(200, lambda: lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=padding))


btn = Button(root, text='Animate', command=animation)
btn.grid(row=1, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks @Bruno Jambeiro! It really made my day! Just one question. Why should we use root.update()? Why isn't it working without that function?

Comment: The screen does not update automatically when you change something on it, so when you change the position of the label the changes will not be shown until the next screen update.In this program, without the root.update() function , many changes  are applied before updating, so only the last one will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way I also use to animate stuff on the screen, I am not able to understand what you were trying to achieve with your code snippet above, I tried making some changes to it but I feel this way is much better and let's you get more control of your window.

This uses the widely used [Canvas](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#:%7E:text=The%20Canvas%20widget%20provides%20structured,various%20kinds%20of%20custom%20widgets.) widget in the tkinter library.

The Canvas is a general purpose widget, You can use it for a lot of things. Visit the hyper link for more clarity

Here is a short example of how you would create text on the screen.

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.title("My animation")
c = Canvas(root)
x = 20 
y = 20    #Instead of using row and column, you simply use x and y co-ordinates
          #We will use these co-ordinates to show where the text is in the starting
my_text = c.create_text(x,y,text = '-----')
c.pack()

# This is all you need to create this text on your screen!
root.mainloop()
```

The idea is that you put your canvas up on your window , and then place *whatever* you want on it.

There are a lot more attributes that you can add to make your text look even better. [Here](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/create_text.html) is an in-depth tutorial on it.

Now that we have made your text widget, It is now time to move it around. Let us move it to 90,20 From our initial position which is 20,20

Here is how we will do it. If we simply move to text object to 90,90, We won't see any animations, it will just directly have it there. So what we will do is first create it at 21,20. Then 22,20. And so on...

We do this really fast till we reach 90,20

This looks like we are moving the text

```py
from tkinter import *
import time
root = Tk()

root.title("My animation")
c = Canvas(root)
x = 20
y = 20    #Instead of using row and column, you simply use x and y co-ordinates
          #We will use these co-ordinates to show where the text is in the starting
my_text = c.create_text(x,y,text = 'weee')
c.pack()

def animation():
    y = 0.1
    x = 0
    for _ in range(1000):
        c.move(my_text,x,y)
        root.update()


anlabel = Button(root,text = 'Animate!',command = animation).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This is not only applicable to text, but everything (like other images)that is there on the canvas. The canvas also has [Events](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) which will let you use mouse-clicks and other keys on the computer too.

I have made some changes from the previous code, But it is executable and you can try it for yourself to see how it works. increasing the value in `time.sleep()` makes the animation slower, the lesser the value, the faster.

Comment: Why are you calling `c.pack()` in the loop? It does absolutely nothing. Also, there's no reason to delete a text object and then create a new text object when you can just move the existing object.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice i will make the following changes

Comment: i have made the change :)

Comment: Thanks @AryanParekh ! However, I want to implement this snippet of code into a bigger program. My goal is that in my main program, I want the user to enter a string in an entry and whenever they hit the "Submit button" this text would move across the page (kind of like imitating a laser) then the text within the entry would disappear because it got struck by this text. My question is that will this method work in a bigger program?

Comment: Yes absolutely!! Canvases are amazing, you can learn a lot more about them on this YouTube series, and also Tkinter itself.https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLCC34OHNcOtoC6GglhF3ncJ5rLwQrLGnV

Comment: I have just demonstrated the use, I used this method in my very own chess game to animate the movement of the pieces , where I just know the starting and end position and also no idea which piece, watch the YouTube series for a ton of information,

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you aren't trying to do something more like the below example? Animating the padding on one of your widgets is going to screw up the rest of your display.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
lbl = Label(root, text='')
lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)


def animation(step=12):
    step = 12 if step < 0 else step
    lbl['text'] = '      ------      '[step:step+6]
    root.after(200, lambda: animation(step-1))


Button(root, text='Animate', command=animation).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w')
root.mainloop()
```